# Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: database, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, putty

am getting the error when trying to connect to remote database i have checked the listener and the services and they are working fine

This my Tnsnames.ora file

```
       XE =
   (DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
)
)

    EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
 (ADDRESS_LIST =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
  )
   (CONNECT_DATA =
  (SID = PLSExtProc)
  (PRESENTATION = RO)
  )
 )

 ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
 (DESCRIPTION = 
  (ADDRESS_LIST = 
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
  ) 
  (CONNECT_DATA = 
  (SID = CLRExtProc) 
  (PRESENTATION = RO) 
 ) 
) 
[Sql Developer][1]
```

Comment: Might I suggest you ask this question on http://serverfault.com/?  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's no "remote" database alias in `TNSNAMES.ORA` file you posted. I believe you should include it and try again.

Comment: I am using an SSH tunnel

Comment: I never used it so I have zero experience in that, but - have a look at this: https://icodealot.com/sql-developer-ssh-tunnels/ based on Kris Rice's and (oh, that) Jeff Smith's presentation. I hope it'll help.